# Change label color on pie-chart of ng2-charts/charts.js

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

Using ng2-charts and have a great pie-chart working and looking great, able to set labels & data as working but cannot change the label color from the grey?

Is that expected or how to over-write the default label color?

Seems like it's setting the default font-color from charts.js (#666), wondering if we can overwrite that in ng2-charts?

**Edit** was using the chartjs-plugin-datalabels plugin and found answer in the docs.

Comment: Note: This is the labels on the pieChart itself. Not the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this ?[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-pie-template-kzxkh7)

```
 legend: {
  display: true,
  labels: {
    fontColor: 'red'
  }
},tooltips :{
  backgroundColor:'white',
  callbacks:{
    labelTextColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) { 
       return "black";     
    },

  }
}
```

Comment: That only changes the legend color? Does not change the color of the labels pie-chart. 

As I typed that and checked out the code realizing it's also on me for example I took is using the data-labels plugin and it's those datalabels that are not updating color.

Looking in that lib now, thanks for the demo!

Comment: Yup that was the issue, found these docs: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration!